# Tempus Dominus Dynamically Changing Options

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I feel like this question is reasonably straightforward. I'm trying to dynamically change options on the Tempus Dominus Bootstrap Datetimepicker.

In particular, I'd like to change the options on one of my datepickers on change of another datepicker on the same page.

```
// Initialisation. 
$(function () {
    $("#datetimepicker_start").datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        date: '{{ widget.value }}',
        minDate: moment() // Today's date.
    });
  });

// Initialisation. 
$(function () {
    $("#datetimepicker_end").datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        date: '{{ widget.value }}',
        minDate: moment() // Today's date.
    });
  });

// Document ready, set up event listener:
 $('#datetimepicker_start').on('change.datetimepicker', function() {
        $("#datetimepicker_end").datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            date: moment()
            minDate:  $('#datetimepicker_start').val() // Trying to limit the mininmum date of this picker
                                                       // to the be value of the first.
        });
    });
```

This is an edited example. I'm currently dynamically inserting the initial date picker instantiation with my template logic as it's part of a form that is loaded in by my web framework.

I can't seem to find a way to update these options on the fly. Explicitly what I'm trying to do is link the two date pickers so that the user can't pick an end date earlier than the start. I've also tried

`$("#datetimepicker_end).minDate = $('#datetimepicker_start).val()`
Or even just a moment() for the value I set in the above line. No change. Any point in the right direction would be great.

EDIT: **SOLUTION:**

```
$('#datetimepicker_start').on('change.datetimepicker', function() {
        var new_min_date = $(this).datetimepicker('date');
        $("#datetimepicker_end").datetimepicker('minDate', new_min_date);
    });
```

**BONUS QUESTION:**
The above method does what I'm trying to achieve, however when setting a minimum date it doesn't allow the end date box to stay blank if it already was. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please, do not make several questions in your own question and answer your own question, do not add the answer in your question. This is not a forum.